# Can grep output only specified groupings line match?

Tags: grep, scripting

I only want to output full line, not only match word

file.txt

```
 Name   Surname   Class   Best-Lesson
1.Nick   Fras      Mat     Chemic
2.Cris   Fras      Chemic  Mat
3.Dani   Cris      Philos  Physical
4.Quar   Qand      Dani    Cris
```

İ want to this, full line

```
grep parameters Dani Chris
output: 3.Dani Cris    Philos   Physical
```

İ dont want thish (with -o)

```
Dani Cris
```

Comment: `grep` will print "full" lines by default. Just try. `grep 'Dani' yourfile`

Comment: No way a `grep 'Dani Chris'` would produce a line with 'Dani Cris'.

Answer (score 1):

Based on OP's comments this grep should be able to produce what OP wants:

```
grep -iE "^[[:digit:]]\.Dani\s{0,}C[h]*ris" input.txt | xargs echo "output:"
```

Or Using `agep` which is absent on my Ubuntu system, so was installed:

```
agrep -1 '[0-9]\.Dani#Chris' input.txt | xargs echo "output:"
```

Result:

```
output: 3.Dani Cris Philos Physical
```

Information:

- `[[:digit:]]\.`, `[0-9]\.`: picks the `3.` part from the input file
- `Dani\s{0,}`, `Dani#Chris`: get tex Dani with any number of space after the name
- `C[h]*ris`: captures `Cris` or `Chris`
- `| xargs echo "Output:"`: pips to xargs and adds text `Output:` before the result

Comment: Why did not you read the question? İ want to just output: output: 3.Dani Cris    Philos   Physical, not dani or nani or NaNi or NAni or others..! Your answer not true and Irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry for the mixup, it should now more relevant!

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by sed,awk and grep too.

Method1 using sed

```
sed -n '/Dani/p’ example.txt | sed -n '/Dani/p’
```

method2 using awk

```
awk '$0 ~ "Dani" && $0 ~ "Cris" {print $0}’ example.txt
```

Method3 using grep

```
grep 'Dani' example.txt  | grep ' Cris'
```

output

```
3.Dani   Cris      Philos  Physical
```

Comment: @Mete Alisa Kindly vote for my answer